# Simplificar un diccionario

Tags: c#, diccionarios

Hola estoy creando un diccionario y estoy casi seguro que se puede simplificar pero no se como. Quiero poner en una sola linea que "2M", "4M", Y "5M" sean igual a 19.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, int> CardRanks = new()
{
    { "2M", 19 },
    { "4M", 19 },
    { "5M", 19 },
};
```

Comment: 2 cosas: 1. Evita llegar a tener la obsesión por tener todo "comprimido", hay algo que se llama "legibilidad de código" y es importante en especial si trabajas en equipo. Tener código "comprimido" a veces juega en contra dependiendo de las habilidades de los demás. Eres libre de considerar esta recomendación y del mismo modo eres libre de ignorarla/rechazarla. 2. Comprimir/simplificar más ese código no se puede, si deseas que esté en una sola línea, puedes eliminar los saltos de línea, aunque habrá diferencia para lo que deseas conseguir. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de un inicializador de índice, haciendo que el valor que corresponde a las llaves indicadas sea igual a **19**:

```
Dictionary<string, int> CardRanks = new()
{
    ["2M"] = ["4M"] = ["5M"] = 19
};
```

También podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
Dictionary<string, int> CardRanks = new Dictionary<string, int>();
CardRanks["2M"] = CardRanks["4M"] = CardRanks["5M"] = 19;
```

Declaras el diccionario y posteriormente le asignas a las llaves correspondientes el valor **19**.